# Do variables accessed within synchronised block must be declared volatile?

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized, volatile

in an example like this:

```
...
    public void foo() {
        ...
        synchronized (lock) {
            varA += some_value;
        }
        ...
    }
...
```

The question is, does varA must be declared *volatile* in order to prevent per-thread caching or it is enough to access it only within *synchronized* blocks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to.
`synchronized` blocks imply a memory barrier.

From [JSR-133](http://www.cs.umd.edu/users/pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#synchronization):

> But there is more to synchronization than mutual exclusion. Synchronization ensures that memory writes by a thread before or during a synchronized block are made visible in a predictable manner to other threads which synchronize on the same monitor. After we exit a synchronized block, we release the monitor, which has the effect of flushing the cache to main memory, so that writes made by this thread can be visible to other threads. Before we can enter a synchronized block, we acquire the monitor, which has the effect of invalidating the local processor cache so that variables will be reloaded from main memory. We will then be able to see all of the writes made visible by the previous release.

Answer (score 0):

So long as every access to it is from within a synchronized block then you are fine.

There is a memory barrier associated with each synchronized block that will make sure the variables accessed within are exposed correctly.